# Returning a string properly in C, multiple times

Tags: c, dynamic, static, allocation

OK, the following way to return a string works fine:

```
char* SU(double V) {
    static char Str[80];
    // Do something
    return Str;
}
printf("%s", SU(A));
```

But the following will fail silently because the string space in memory is the same at the end of both calls:

```
printf("%s %s", SU(A), SU(B));
```

How can I do this cleanly and simply ? I was looking at alloca() but I don't think I can return a string allocated with alloca(), can I ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proper way to return a string in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31411831/proper-way-to-return-a-string-in-c)

Comment: Why not allocate 2 buffers on call site and pass those to `SU`?

Comment: Functions can allocate memory and return a pointer to this newly-allocated memory. Many programmers don't like this approach since they consider it a safer strategy to have the function which allocates memory be the function that frees it.

Comment: _I was looking at alloca() but I don't think I can return a string allocated with alloca(), can I ?_ . No you can't, but using `malloc` would be OK.

Answer (score 3):

It is always best to leave allocation to the caller. The standard way to return strings from functions in C is through parameter:

```
void SU (double V, char* str, size_t size);
```

Or in modern C you could do:

```
void SU (double V, size_t size, char str[static size]);
```

([See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430315/what-is-the-purpose-of-static-keyword-in-array-parameter-of-function-like-char))

Answer (score 2):

Serialise the calls to `SU`:

```
printf("%s ", SU(A));
printf("%s" , SU(B));
```

Alternatively, copy the returned strings:

```
char *sua = strdup(SU(A));
char *sub = strdup(SU(B));
printf("%s %s", sua, sub);
free(sua);
free(sub);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your function to allocate a string on the heap instead.

```
char* SU(double V) {
    char* Str = malloc(80);
    // Do something
    return Str;
}
```

don't forget to free the returned string once you are done with it.

```
char* a = SU(A);
char* b = SU(B);
printf("%s %s", a, b);
free(b);
free(a);
```

Comment: Yes, that works, but that makes things complicated for the caller, which I was trying to keep simple.

Comment: @dargaud the other way to make it less "complicated" would be to pass the Str array to the function.

Comment: Does `static char* Str = malloc(80);` even compile??? I doubt that very much... But even if it does somehow, then I'd expect `malloc` to be invoked only once, in which case, your second call to `free` should yield undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the perfectly valid solutions you have proposed, I thought about a different approach which can be applied in this case, since the objective was to feed the returned strings to printf: it's to use the GNU C register_printf_function function to add custom format strings to printf.

More info [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Customizing-Printf.html) and an example [here for MAC addresses](http://codingrelic.geekhold.com/2008/12/printf-acular.html)